# Accessing external hosts from docker container

Tags: docker

I am trying to dockerize my application. I have two servers, say server1 and server2. Server1 uses webservice hosted on server2. I have this in my 
/etc/default/docker on server1:

```
DOCKER_OPTS="--dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 8.8.4.4 --iptables=false"
```

As I understand this prevents docker from making any changes to iptables, overriding UFW settings. The UFW status shows this:

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere
2375/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
2375/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Now the trouble is I am not able to access server2 from my app which runs 
in a container on server1. If I don't use the --iptables=false flag then I can access server2. What can I do to access server2 from the container without having to sacrifice UFW ?

If it matters , both server1 and server2 are on digitalocean and have private networking enabled.

Comment: Several misconceptions there. The DNS option sets the DNS to Google's ones. Don't have anything to do with messing with iptablea per se, but if you try to resolve your internal infrastructure names with them you won't (or shouldn't). Try to access by ip, it should work unless ufw is limiting outbound connections from server1. For a more pure containers approach, you could use ambassador containers or make a network between the containers with weave.

Comment: By default the iptables option is not there. It is risky. It completely bypasses the UFW rules and allows any traffic from anywhere to the docker containers. So iptables=false is definitely required. I didnt know the dns points to google servers. But in any case the server2 is publicly accessible too . I just mentioned the private networking in case it helps in any alternative solution. I will check out weave and ambassador . Thanks!

Comment: @everydayapps have you found a solution?

Comment: Nope. Feeling much less enthusiastic about docker now. Switched back to my older configuration :-(